# How to resolve the bundle info:error code:4 while running HMS Map Application?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I am running HMS Map application getting the following error
**Failed to get huawei_module_maps bundle info, error code:4**
How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please confirm if the map bundles are added before loading the map in the code. Please check below code snippet regarding the same.

```
    Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle("MapViewBundleKey");
    }
```

Make sure MapViewBundlekey is been added.